Where does an Ubuntu EC2 instance download files to by default during its execution of the user data script?
Suppose the user data script is as follows:
#!/bin/bash
apt update -y

apt install -y curl

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"

Where exactly, will awscliv2.zip be installed to?

It's not so much where it downloads to as where the userdata script is run. Also, it's run as root so you don't need to sudo. Also, note that Ubuntu server AMIs often already include the awscli.

@jarmod Amazon Linux typically includes it, but IME Ubuntu often does not. That's a bit beside the point though, I just wanted to give an example of a file that someone might download.

OK, makes sense. I think a fuller answer would actually require knowledge of cloud-init because afaik it decides, or it's implicitly a consequence of how cloud-init runs, where the current working directory is when the userdata script is run. All of this can be avoided though by downloading to an explicit folder or streaming the output of wget directly into unzip, without intermediate storage to disk, for example.

After experimenting a little, I see that it downloads to the "/" directory by default in Ubuntu 22.
